# How should I think when solving probability problems? Better tools than "telling stories"?

Tags: probability

I feel like I have to invent a new method every time I stumble upon any problem that is just a bit more complicated. I think that's because I solve them by telling myself "stories" and they are just convincing. I can't analyze them logically. I have to find the gaps in my thinking just by intuition. **What mental model/math tools work better?**

**Example**: What is the probability of exactly two numbers being the same if I pick 3 numbers, each from {1, 2, 3, ... 9}.
So `9, 1, 1` is ok, `1, 9, 1` is also ok but `9, 9, 9` and `1, 2, 3` aren't.

The answer is $\frac{9\cdot8\cdot3}{9^3} = \frac{8}{27}$. I understand the solution but I don't know why my solution is wrong. Or rather I don't have the tools to just see that it's wrong.

**My solution 1**:
$$
P(A) = P( \text{"first" number is in {1, 2, ... 9}} ) \cdot P(\text{"second" number is not the same as the "first" one}) \cdot P(\text{"third" number is the same as "first"})
$$

$$
P(A) = 1 \cdot \frac{9 - 1}{9} \cdot \frac{1}{9} = \frac{8}{81}
$$

My thinking is that "first", "second" and "third" are meaningless since they can also be in any other order. The important part is that 2 of them must be the same and one of them must be different. But it turns out that's wrong and I have no idea why the order sometimes matter and sometimes it doesn't.

**My solution 2**:
I pick 2 different numbers, `a` and `b`. There are $\binom{9}{2} = 9 \cdot 4$ possibilities. I can arrange them in 3 orders `aab`, `aba`, `baa`. I can pick 3 numbers in $9^3$ ways. So
$$
P(A) = \frac{9 \cdot 4 \cdot 3}{9^3} = \frac{4}{27}
$$

Comment: Understand Bayes formula and its terms and simply "slot" the values into the terms.

Comment: Could you show me how it would work in this problem?

Comment: In your solution 1, you assume that the different number is second. You omitted the possibilities "it is first" and "it is third". Multiply your result by 3 and you're done.

Comment: I don't assume it's second. I only assume there's only one if it. And it's not like I assume it's some particular number. There would be cases when 1 is the "first" and "third" number and 9 the "second" one and cases when 9 is the "first" and "third" and 1 is the "second" one. The order doesn't matter.

Comment: That's like saying there are only $21$ equally likely outcomes when you roll a pair of dice.  After all, $1$-$5$ is the same as $5$-$1$, etc.

Comment: So should I solve all problems as if order matters? Or is there some test I can do to tell if it does or not?

Answer (score 1):

This is called sampling with replacement (because you put the numbers back into the pool). Success is sampling one particular number twice and one other number once. The probability of this event is 
$$
P(E) = \frac{1}{9^2} \times \frac{8}{9} = \frac{8}{9^3}
$$
Now, this accounts for just one sequence (e.g. 991, 992, etc). Since order doesn't matter, you need to account for cases like (199, 919, etc). You can have this event in $\binom{3}{2}$ ways (2 slots out of 3). This probability is 
$$
P(E') = \binom{3}{2}P(E)
$$
Now, since all outcomes are equally likely, you need to consider all numbers you have, and the probability of success is:
$$
P(S) = 9 \times P(E') = 27\times P(E) = \frac{27 \times 8}{9^3} 
$$

Comment: Thanks! That makes it much clearer. I'll try to adapt this type of thinking to other problems.

Comment: Feel free to accept solutions if it answers your question